# Wrapping a shell in Python and then launching subprocesses in said shell

Tags: python, subprocess

Python can be used to spawn a shell and communicate with it:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['cmd'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) # use 'bash' if Linux.
```

With this set-up sending a command such as 'echo foo' or 'cd' command works. However, problems arise when we try to use a program inside of the cmd line. For example, in a normal shell you can enter a python shell by typing "python", run Python code (and report printouts, etc), and then leave with "quit()". This SSCCE attempts to do so (Python 3.10) but fails:

```
import subprocess, threading, os, time

proc = 'cmd' if os.name=='nt' else 'bash'

messages = []

p = subprocess.Popen([proc], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
exit_loops = False
def read_stdout():
    while not exit_loops:
        msg = p.stdout.readline()
        messages.append(msg.decode())
def read_stderr():
    while not exit_loops:
        msg = p.stderr.readline()
        messages.append(msg.decode())
threading.Thread(target=read_stdout).start()
threading.Thread(target=read_stderr).start()

# This works:
p.stdin.write('echo foo\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(0.125)
print('Messages echo test:', messages)
del messages[:]

# This fails:
p.stdin.write('python\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.write('x = 123\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.write('print("x is:",x)\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.write('y = nonexistant_var\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.write('quit()\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Messages python test:', messages)

# This generates a python error b/c quit() didn't actually quit:
p.stdin.write('echo bar\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(0.125)
print('Messages echo post-python test:', messages)
```

The output of the SSCCE can handle the first echo command, but cannot handle the Python properly. Also, it can't seem quit() the python script and return to the normal shell. Instead it generates a syntax error:

```
Messages echo test: ['Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.1219]\r\n', '(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n', '\r\n', 'path\\to\\folder\n', 'foo\r\n', '\r\n']
Messages python test: ['path\\to\\folder>python\n']
Messages echo post-python test: ['path\\to\\folder>python\n', '  File "<stdin>", line 5\r\n', '    echo bar\r\n', '         ^\r\n', 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\n', '\r\n']
```

Once it opened the python shell it got "stuck". However, the terminal handles Python shells just fine (and other programs). How can we do so?